# Heatmap vs Scrollmap

Tags: scrolling, heatmaps

I have run a small test (1,000 views, ~650 clicks) for a homepage of a site using CrazyEgg.

Of all the clicked areas, the "2" and "Next" from the only pagination buttons right at the bottom of the page (about 4 viewports down) are the hottest of the whole heatmap. Somewhat contrary to this though, is their scrollmap, which indicates nobody is scrolling to that area of the page (0 ~ 10% coolness by their scale).

Which one is to be valued?

Comment: Maybe you're using rollover buttons which are not visible to CrazyEgg?

Comment: just simple buttons, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think the results are contrary?

Without seeing the page it's hard to understand exactly what's going on - but the results don't seem contradictory.

For example you could explain it like this: Few people scrolled. However all those people probably didn't find what they wanted (which is why they scrolled) and would then naturally click on the next button (if they didn't get bored and go away).

You should value all the results - and look at  the context of the interaction and the users to figure out what's happening and what, if anything, needs improving.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I think that explains it. The sheer number of people who went to the bottom were looking for more and so clicked to the 2nd/next page in such high volume.

I'll do further analysis to determine what % of total visitors are those who don't find what they are looking for on the homepage.